# Get data as rows from array inside JSON column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table which the `'Preference'` column stores JSON strings.

a) I would like to get the `type` from `companytype` as **rows**. 
 In my attempt on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fb445/2) I get the five rows but no data in them.

```
SELECT z.[Type]
FROM FinPreferences p
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Preference,'$.companytype.type') WITH (
    [Type] INT
) z
WHERE PreferenceID=1
```

b) How can I get the results as one string **row** i.e

> 1,2,3,4,5

This is the data inside the `Preference` column

```
   {
    "companysize":{"min":0,"max":5},
    "distance":{"min":100,"max":200},
    "companytype":{"type":[1,2,3,4,5]},
    "budget":{"min":1000,"max":2000}
    }
```

[Fiddle is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fb445/2)

Comment: Post the table schema, queries in the question itself.

Comment: you can use JSON_QUERY

Comment: @ManojNaik there's nothing wrong with `OPENJSON`. JSON_QUERY won't return a rowset either

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either remove the `WITH` clause and use the `value` field to retrieve the array's values, eg:

```
SELECT z.value as Type
FROM FinPreferences p
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Preference,'$.companytype.type') z
WHERE PreferenceID=1
```

Or use just `$` as the path in the `WITH` clause :

```
SELECT z.Type
FROM FinPreferences p
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Preference,'$.companytype.type') 
            WITH ( Type int '$') z
WHERE PreferenceID=1
```

`WITH` applies to the results returned by [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). The path `$.companytype.type` is just an array of integers, it doesn't have any other attributes

Comment: This works. How would I get the results as one result such as 1,2,3,4,5 which is the part B?

Comment: Tried this but I get no values: SELECT  JSON_VALUE( Preference, '$.companytype.type' ) AS [Type]
FROM FinPreferences p
WHERE p.PreferenceID=1

Comment: @alwaysVBNET that's a different question. `JSON_VALUE` returns scalar values, eg `JSON_VALUE( Preference, '$.companytype.type[1]' )` will return `2`. You need `JSON_QUERY` if you expect to return multiple values, like the contents of an array, eg `JSON_QUERY( Preference, '$.companytype.type' )` will return `[1,2,3,4,5]`